# Can I Use vector's Fill Constructor to Create a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector, constructor

I want to create a multi-dimensional array, let's say `m` x `n` Can I accomplish something like that using the fill constructor of a `vector`?

For example:

```
vector<vector<int>> foo(n, vector<int>(m));
```

The closest thing I saw addressing this on StackOverflow was: [How do I declare and initialize a 2d int vector in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2733816/2642059) But it looked like there was still some question of whether it was legal.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and it seems to work fine.

**EDIT:**

I'm also going to guess here that this creates a temporary `vector` of size `m` copies it `n` times and then destroys it.
Will the compiler optimize out that temporary construction? I'm hoping the answer to that is yes, cause using a `move` here seems like it wouldn't accomplish what I hope either.

Comment: I don't see any question about its legality. This is fine.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix