# C++ Randomly select non-empty element of std::vector<std::vector> >

Tags: c++, vector, random

I am given a large vector that itself contains vectors of a specific data type e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<double> > foo`. I am trying to retrieve a random element foo[idx] from foo such that `foo[idx]` is non-empty or respectively `foo[idx].empty() == false`.

My naive guess would be to select random elements from `foo` until my constraint `foo[idx].empty() == false` is fulfilled.

However it is very likely the case that `foo` is very sparsely filled with non-empty vectors. Hence, my approach would quite likely be devastatingly slow.

Are there better approaches or should i think of a completely different data structure?

Comment: `std::shuffle` then iterate until you find one.

Comment: @iBug `std::shuffle` will not help the program just condense it.

Comment: @JakeFreeman It's also fine to create an index array then shuffle the indices.

Comment: The random approach is good, especially if you can cache the indexes you have already tried so you don't try them again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintain an auxiliary vector with the index of the non empty elements and get a random element from there

Comment: This idea is not that efficient because you are storing 2x memory and it takes time to constantly make sure they are the same

Comment: It takes constant time to maintain  using a hash table. About the memory, yes, it takes memory. but memory is free :D

Answer (score 2):

You could build an index of the nonempty elements:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > foo;
std::vector<decltype (foo)::iterator> nonempty;
for (auto it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end; ++it)
{
  if (! it->empty())
  {
    nonempty.push_back(it);
  }
}
std::random_device rd;
// random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case) 
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
// create a guaranteed unbiased index (unlike using modulo on rand)
std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> uni_idx_dist(0,nonempty.size() - 1); 

auto &random_nonempty = *nonempty[uni_idx_dist(rng)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract an index of what's non-empty, then select one:

```
std::vector<int> ind;
for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++){
    if (! foo[i].empty()) {
        ind.push_back(i);
    }
}
int i = rand() % int.size();
return int[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a vector of references to non empty vectors.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using int_vec_t = std::vector<int>;
    std::vector<int_vec_t> v = {
        {0, 1, 2}, {}, {}, {3, 4, 5},
        {}, {6, 7, 8}, {}, {}, {9}, {10, 11}
    };

    // You can't put reference direcly, so use reference_wrapper instead
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int_vec_t> > nonempty;
    nonempty.reserve(v.size());
    // "copy" non empty vectors. (Doesn't do copy, actually)
    std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(nonempty), [](const int_vec_t& v) { return !v.empty();});
    if (nonempty.empty())
        return 0;
    // pick an element
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, nonempty.size() - 1);
    const int_vec_t& result = nonempty[dis(gen)];
    // dump result
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here:

1. The ordinal `vector` is sparsely populated
2. [A `vector` of `vector`s is wateful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38244435/2642059)

To solve problem **1** I'd recomend the use of a `map<size_t, vector<double>> foo` this will allow you to use non-linear indices, but it won't require the population of the intervening empty `vector`s. Selection of a random populated element here just involves advancing the iterator to point to the appropriate element. For example `result` will be the const-iterator to a random key-value `pair` in `foo`:

```
const auto idx = foo.empty() ? 0U : std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}() % size(foo);
const auto result = next(cbegin(foo), idx);
```

The solution to **1** and **2** would be a bit more elaborate, as I'd recommend doing away with `vector`s all together in favor of `multimap<size_t, double> foo` This contains all the benefits of the `map` solution, but the trade off is that the keys must be iterated using `upper_bound`. Additionally, because `multimap` does not store a key count, `size_t keyCount` would need to be maintained alongside the `multimap`. Or presuming it was a temporary initialized to `0U` it could be wastefully found at the time it is needed: `for(auto it = cbegin(foo); it != cend(foo); it = foo.upper_bound(it->first)) ++keyCount;` Using `keyCount` we can again find `result` which here will be an const-iterator to the first of the elements matching the random key:

```
int idx = keyCount == 0U ? 0 : std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}() % keyCount;
auto result = cbegin(foo);

while(idx-- > 0) result = foo.upper_bound(result->first);
```