# Is There a way to Find the Number of Keys in a multimap Inline?

Tags: c++, key, size, inline, multimap

A `multimap`'s `size` reports the number of values it contains. I'm interested in the number of keys it contains. For example, given `multimap<int, double> foo` I'd like to be able to do this:

```
const auto keyCount = ???
```

One way to get this is to use a `for`-loop on a zero initialized `keyCount`:

```
for(auto it = cbegin(foo); foo != cend(foo); it = foo.upper_bound(foo->first)) ++keyCount;
```

This however, does not let me perform the operation inline. So I can't initialize a `const auto keyCount`.

A solution could be a lambda or function which wraps this `for`-loop such as:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
size_t getKeyCount(const multimap<Key, Value>& arg) {
    size_t result = 0U;

    for(auto it = cbegin(foo); foo != cend(foo); it = foo.upper_bound(foo->first)) ++result;
    return result;
}
```

But I was hoping for something provided by the standard. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Maybe std::multimap is not the best data structure for you. For example `std::map<key,std::vector<value>>` could work better.

Comment: what about `const auto keyCount = std::accumulate(...` that wraps the for loop?

Comment: @Slava That suffers from the `vector` of `vector`s problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38244435/2642059 (Though this may still be my best option, I'd still like an answer to the question.)

Comment: @tobi303 I doubt `std::accumulate()` can jump over unique keys

Comment: @tobi303 I was going to lash out that that would require me to step through all the elements in the `multimap` but as I think about it I'm pretty sure `upper_bound` is doing just that. I suppose to your point we could probably do this using `count_if` or `for_each` as well :( I'm assuming that's going to be as good of an answer as I'm going to get, if you type up I'll accept.

Comment: @Slava, I... don't think that `upper_bound` jumps keys does it?

Comment: @Slava Op, no, cancel that it does a binary search: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound#Complexity

Comment: it was just a blind guess. If I find the time later I will write an answer, but atm my compile times are rather short :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1<sup>st</sup>, [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) doesn't contain a key count naively. So your question then is about how to use something from the [algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to find the count. The 2 constraints you have placed that preclude everything in the library are:

1. Must be used inline, so a count, not an iterator must be returned
2. Must perform at least as well as [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) used in a lambda, which has time complexity: *O(log n)*

**1** leaves us with: `count`, `count_if`, `for_each`, as well as most of the algorithms in the [numeric library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric)

**2** eliminates consideration of all of these as each of them has time complexity: *O(n)*

As such your `getKeyCount` is preferable to any other option that the standard supplies.

---

Just a comment about another option that may be presented: the maintenance of `keyCount` whenever something is added or removed from `foo`, this may seem workable, but it requires a check before each insert if the inserted key exists, and a check after each removal if the removed key still exists. Aside from this, there is also the consideration of the danger of multi-threaded inoperability and the loss of code readability, where it's not clear that this `keyCount` must be maintained along with `foo`. Ultimately this a bad idea unless the key count is taken significantly more frequently than `foo` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in in the standard to do this. Consider that your count function works because a multimap is internally sorted. Typical implementations such as libstdc++ use red-black trees for the internal representation. You would need to walk the tree in order to count all the (unique) keys. It's unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

If you only are creating multimap and inserting values in it, you can keep a companion map to record different types of keys. That size of that map will give you key count.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment :( See also the problems presented in the second half of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928082/2642059