# Problems with 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector

Are there any problems associated with

```
vector< vector<int> > v(m, vector<int>(n));
```

Is it safer to write:

```
vector< vector<int> > v(m);
for (size_t i=0; i<m; i++)
    v[i].resize(n);
```

Comment: The first one is less error prone.

Comment: In the future I strongly advise against the sort of rude rant you originally had at the end of this question.

Comment: The edited/removed statement is not what I would call "friendly" or welcoming

Comment: I remember back in '98 or so applying for a job where one of the requirements was 5+ years of experience in Java. At the time that pretty much meant only James Gosling could apply.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What are the Issues with a vector-of-vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244435/what-are-the-issues-with-a-vector-of-vectors) and [C++ Matrix Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 I still get job adverts requiring more experience in a technology than the technology has existed for! Recruiters are silly.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is safer, especially if the second dimension, `n` was very large. The resizing approach would be preferred in memory limited, embedded systems programming. Take the example of

```
vector< vector<int> > v(2, vector<int>(1'000'000));
```

Constructing the 2D vector of vectors would (for most compilers) require an additional `4'000'000` bytes (32 bit ints) compared to the resizing approach as it would create a vector of `1,000,000` needed to initialize the vectors. This is required because the `vector<int>(1'000'000)` must be constructed. It is then used to initialize each of the `m` row vectors. After execution it is destroyed so the increased memory requirement is short lived. Thus, I would prefer the second approach which does not require construction of an initializing vector.

That said, I quite agree with the point that a vector of vectors is a particularly bad approach to creating dynamic, 2D vectors unless each row is to have variable numbers of columns.

See my answer here which shows a short, efficient, class that can be used for 2D dynamic vectors.
[Statically declared 2-D array C++ as data member of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123452/statically-declared-2-d-array-c-as-data-member-of-a-class/36123944#36123944)

Comment: This is either wrong or so poorly worded that it's wrong. Both options will consume the same storage in the same block sizes.

Comment: @user4581301 Only after the formation of the vector of vectors. During formation it requires more memory.

Comment: @doug Presumably you're talking about the ctor argument. I don't know whether it is copied _n-1_ times then moved at the end (which removes your concern) but it is certainly possible. Worth investigating.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Construction of `vector<int>(n)` used to initialize. While not required, what compiler doesn't?

Comment: Actually thinking about it, that arg is `const T&` not `T&&` so it must be copied for all elements. So, you are correct, there is (briefly) one additional "row" in memory.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. Recommend editing paragraphs three and four to make where the extra row is coming from brutally clear.

Comment: Yep agreed answer could be clearer but have upvoted pre-emptively as the argument is sound.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Good point about `const T&`